# Which c++ compiler to use qt5 win7

Tags: qt

trying to create a GUI for the first time.

I've decided to try QT 5.0, but it keeps giving me the error:

> error: Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure a
>   compiler in the kit options.

I go into kit options, and I can choose a number of different Visual Studio 11 compilers, or a MinGW compiler.

I have tried pointing the MinGW compiler to several different .exe files in the minGW bin dir, like c++.exe, gcc.exe, g++.exe, etc. I still receive the error message.

Then I read somewhere that I need to use MSVC10 to compile, however I can not find this compiler anywhere.

I just need to create a simple window with a couple labels and text boxes and a button, and I can't even get as far as creating a window.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You should use the search function, there are lot of questions about this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608596/qt5-beta2-qt-creator-2-6-msvc-error-qt-creator-needs-a-compiler-set-up-to-bui & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519743/vc-compiler-for-qt-creator

Answer (score 2):

I had to install MSVC2010, and use that compiler.

Answer (score 1):

First configure a compiler in the "Compilers" tab of the "Build & Run" section in the Creator options. Then you can chose a configured compiler in a kit. Then set your project to use that kit.